# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}g'(x)f(g(x),x)dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, contour-integration

I know how to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}g'(x)f(g(x))dx$$ for $g$ differentiable, I just need to take $s = g(x)$ and then I find $$\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(s)ds$$
But what happens when $f$ depends explicitely on $x$, i.e. how to do the integration for
$$ \int_{0}^{1} g'(x)f(g(x),x)dx$$
For now, my only idea is to write this integral as
$$ \int_{0}^{1}(g'(x), 1). (f(g(x),x),0)dx $$
so that I have $(g(x),x)'$. But it does not seem to work ...

Comment: How does this question relate to contours?

Comment: Because my intuition is that I need to integrate on the curve $(g(x),x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: The word "contour" is usually used for complex numbers, though.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of notation ? I mean, is there really a fundamental difference between integrating a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ over a curve and integrating the same function in the complex plane ?

Comment: You’re assuming in your easier-case example that $g$ is monotonic?

Comment: No, just that it is differentiable. By setting $s=g(x)$ I obtain $ds=g'(x)dx$ and I directly obtain $\int f(s)ds$. The bounds of integration are obtained by taking $x=1$ so $s=g(1)$ and $x=0$ so $s=g(0)$.

Comment: How does that work when $g(x) := \sin\pi x$?

Comment: And $f(x)=x$ for example ? Then $\int_{0}^{1}\pi cos(\pi x) sin(\pi x)dx  = \frac{1}{2}(sin(\pi)^2 - sin(0)^2) = 0 = \int_{0}^{0}sds$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, I think I found the answer. So, I have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}g'(x)f(g(x),x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}(g'(x),1).(f(g(x),x),0)dx$$
I define the function $L : \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ by
$$ L(\gamma (x)) = (f(\gamma (x)), 0)$$
where $\gamma (x) = (g(x),x)$. The problem is therefore to integrate
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\gamma '(x) L(\gamma (x))dx $$
At this point, it looks very similar to $\int g' f(g)$. I set $s = (s_{1},s_{2}) = \gamma (x)$, which gives us $ds = (ds_{1},ds_{2}) = \gamma'(x) dx$. The previous integral becomes
$$ \int_{\gamma (0)}^{\gamma (1)} L(s)ds = \int_{\gamma (0)}^{\gamma (1)}(f(s),0)ds$$
which concludes the proof.

Comment: This needs your better scrutiny at this point.

Comment: Is there an error in the argument?